# MVC Route with condition checking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have routes below in my MVC4...

```
routes.MapRoute("Account", "Account/{action}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Admin", "Admin/{action}", new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" });            
routes.MapRoute("Custom", "{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

...and need to find a way to route all url which has `2` symbol(`www.domain.com/word2pdf`) in url to action Index and pass url path(`word2pdf`) as `api` parameter.

```
public ActionResult Index(string api)
{ 
}
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Check out using [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Murali said, the proper way is to use Attribute Routing, but that's a new feature for mvc5 only.

If you want or have to stay on mvc4:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "SomeRoutingName",
  url: "{api}",
  defaults: new { controller = "SomeControllerName", action = "Index"},
  constraints: new { api= ".+2.+"});
```

Also just for some lol's, this should also work:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "SomeRoutingName",
  url: "{partA}2{partB}",
  defaults: new { controller = "SomeControllerName", action = "Index" });
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string partA, string partB)
{ 
     var api = string.Concat(partA,"2",partB);
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, both suggestions works as expected!